# How can I read an Azure Blob Storage file direclty from an Azure Databricks Notebook

Tags: azure, scala, apache-spark, azure-blob-storage, databricks

When I run the below code locally it works, but when I run it inside of Azure Databricks it hangs forever and never stops running.  I know that the `endpoint` and `sasToken`  is correct because it works locally.  But it does not work when I run it directly from an Azure Databricks Notebook.  Any ideas?

```
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobClientBuilder
import java.io.InputStream

val input: InputStream = new BlobClientBuilder()
      .endpoint(s"https://<storage-account>.blob.core.windows.net")
      .sasToken("<sas-token>")
      .containerName("<container-name>>")
      .blobName("<blob-name>")
      .buildClient()
      .openInputStream()
```

Comment: have you checked settings of storage firewall? Does the Databricks VNet added to it?

Comment: @AlexOtt, when I go into my Azure Storage Account -> Networking -> Under the "Firewalls and virtual networks" tab -> the "Enable from all networks" option is currently selected.  So I don't believe there are any firewall restrictions enabled.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that this code used to work at one point going against the exact same storage account / container / file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using shaded jars (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) within my app. This example here helped me walk through setting that up. https://github.com/anuchandy/azure-sdk-in-data-bricks.  See below for an updated example.  Now I can prefix my `import` with the shaded group id that I created in my POM plugin config. My code in Databricks now knows exactly what dependency to use when reading from blob storage.

```
import <MY.GROUP.ID>.com.azure.storage.blob.BlobClientBuilder
import java.io.InputStream

val input: InputStream = new BlobClientBuilder()
      .endpoint(s"https://<storage-account>.blob.core.windows.net")
      .sasToken("<sas-token>")
      .containerName("<container-name>>")
      .blobName("<blob-name>")
      .buildClient()
      .openInputStream()
```

Azure Blob Storage Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
    <version>12.14.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Maven Shade Plugin:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass><MY.MAIN.CLASS></mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                        <!--Transforms META-INF/services (essential for azure-core relocation)-->
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                    </transformers>
                    <relocations>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>com.fasterxml.jackson</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>${project.groupId}.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <!--In Databricks 10.2 you nay also need to relocate reactor netty classes-->
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>io.netty</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>${project.groupId}.shaded.io.netty</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>reactor</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>${project.groupId}.shaded.reactor</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <!--Databricks brings its own version of azure-core which may be incompatible with blob storage version. Relocate azure-core so we don't collide with it-->
                            <pattern>com.azure</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>${project.groupId}.shaded.com.azure</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                    </relocations>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check whether Secure transfer Enable or not. Go to azure storage account  -> Settings go to the configuration you will find Secure transfer. If not, enable it. The secure transfer provides the security of your storage account by only allowing requests to the storage account by a secure connection.

> **Is there any alternative options available ?**

**There are different alternative options available:**  Reading Azure Blob Storage file directly from Azure Databricks Notebook.

- **Option 1:** [Accessing Azure Blob Storage from Azure Databricks by Gauri Mahajan](https://www.sqlshack.com/accessing-azure-blob-storage-from-azure-databricks/)
- **Option 2:** [Access Azure Blob storage using SAS token provided by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage#access-azure-blob-storage-using-the-dataframe-api).